# How does WhatsApp add their icon to their contacts tab and favourites tab in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, ios7, addressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I have been working on app which needs phone contacts,i am able to get the name and phone numbers from the AddressBook.
But want to make tab like whats app has done,they open the default Address Book with icon of whats app in in front of contact number if the user is available on WhatsApp and also the status of the contact person.
How does the WhatsApp add icon to the number and add status to their contacts tab?
Also i am confused whether the contacts tab in WhatsApp using default UIAddressBookController or they made custom.
For more clarity please check the screenshot that i have added.[image]

Kindly suggest me how can i achieve this in my app using the default ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that this is a custom view controller that mimicks the original detail view of a contact. It looks similar but is still different. There is no "groups in common" or status or whatsoever in the standard detail view. Also, this is a standard system component that you can and should not override.

They will probably be using the API to access the Contacts and present them in their own view controllers.

Comment: the contacts tab in whats app is exactly the same as in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController,just the groups UIBarButtonItem is missing.I doubt that they are using their custom controller.

Comment: Then your question was misleading. You posted a screenshot from a person's details which clearly is custom. But the contact list is probably custom too as Apple discourages you from subclassing them.